# Tooltip over favorite tag confuses me

Tags: feature-request, tooltips

When I mouseover the favorite the question It says "This is a favorite question(Click again to undo)" but I haven't set the question as favorite.
and When I click on favorite element it shows same error message

So this creates confusion that whether current question is a favorite or not for a newbie, I am new to this site so I found this confusing, After several use I came to know that if it is yellow then it is a favorite question, otherwise it is not... Would someone please try to solve this ambiguity

Comment: It is consistent with the tooltips on the upvote and downvote arrows. After a click or two, I think it's clear what all of those buttons do, so I don't think this needs to be changed. Regardless of what I think, if you think the text is confusing or ambiguous, you should suggest specific phrasing that would be better.

Comment: @BilltheLizard To be honest - it is not consistent - when you hover over up/down there is no text '(Click again to undo)', it shows only when the vote is already done. And in case of favorite the message doesn't change no matter if it is selected or not. And that is confusing for Parag. The message, if not selected, should not have that (Click again to undo) part - something like 'Click to make it favorite question'.

Comment: @Gas Ah, you're right. I didn't notice that the parenthetical part disappears and reappears on the vote buttons.